# Show amount of times SELECT items have been used, then order that by ASC or DESC

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Bestemmingscode, COUNT(*) as aantal
FROM Reis
GROUP BY Bestemmingscode
;
```

It currently display like:

- ALANY  2
- BALI   1
- BANK   3
- BRUS   1
- etc.

But it should be like

- BRUS   1
- BALI   1
- ALANY  2
- BANK   3
- etc.

It should be based on the amount of times showing, and not the name. It can be either DESC or ASC that doesnt really matter.

Comment: The order of result rows is undefined when a query doesn't contain an `ORDER BY` clause. In spite of the output being ordered by `Bestemmingscode` in your example, this is in no way guaranteed; it's just what the DBMS happened to choose to do. Always use `ORDER BY` whan you want your results in a specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `ORDER BY`.  Just add:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

to the end of your query.  Add `DESC` if you want a descending order.